# alias a namespace globaly for the entire project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, namespaces

is it possible to create a new alias for a given namespace for the entire project?
that is i dont want to write a "using DO = App.Do.App33;" in each cs file of the project.
but i want to do it one time in some configuration or maybe in some cs file.
and then simply DO will refer to App.Do.App33 in the entire Application.

Comment: C# really lacks that feature.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that for the entire project.  You're limited to the file level.