# c# - Use alias in another file

Tags: c#, namespaces

Is it possible to use an alias defined in one file throughout an assembly?

For eg. in Foo.cs I have

```
using IO = System.IO;
namespace Foo
{}
```

How can I use the alias "IO" in FooBar.cs

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? You can add using IO = System.IO in every file you want..

Comment: Adding this in every file is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [alias a namespace globaly for the entire project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799466/alias-a-namespace-globaly-for-the-entire-project)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this ? If you want to reducre typing work you may create a templates for your class files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

`The scope of a using directive is limited to the file in which it appears.`

So the answer is No. You cannot define an alias in one file and use it throughout assembly

Comment: A work around would be inheriting `class IO : System.IO { }`.

Comment: @hrzafer can you write an example?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to define global/shared `using` directive aliases. I recently considered this topic while working with a rather long class name across multiple files and methods.

One possibility to consider is using a code-generation tool that will add the alias to new files. This seems a bit pedantic however as it is pretty easy to just copy+paste the alias for every file that needs it.

Another option that one might consider is mentioned in [hrzafer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339246/hrzafer) comment:

> A work around would be inheriting `class IO : System.IO`

Ignoring the bad syntax -- `System.IO` is a `namespace` and cannot be inherited by a `class` -- what [hrzafer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339246/hrzafer) may have meant is something more like:

> `class Dir : System.IO.DirectoryInfo`

Although this could work as a makeshift alias with simple classes, it could very well cause confusion since the point of inheritance is to reuse, extend, and modify the behavior defined in the base class.

Also, this approach doesn't work for `sealed` or `static` classes.

Comment: This really should have been a comment.