# How do I add a shorter alias to a namespace used by another project?

Tags: c#, namespaces, alias

Good afternoon!

I have two C# projects in a Visual Studio solution with the following namespace structure (reflects directory layout):

```
MySolution
|-- MyLibrary
|   |-- App_Code
|   |   |-- Entities
|   |   |   `-- ...
|   |   `-- ...
|   `-- MainClass.cs
`-- MyApplication
    |-- App_Code
    |   `-- ...
    `-- Main.cs
```

In the *MyApplication* project I'd like to use a few classes from the *Entities* namespace of the *MyLibrary* project without having to specify its fully qualified name each time:

```
...
// using MyLibrary.App_Code.Entities; // too long and ugly
using MyLibrary.Entities; // much better

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Main
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I define `MyLibrary.Entities` as an alias to `MyLibrary.App_Code.Entities` inside MyLibrary (and thus avoiding the need to do it manually each time a component is used)?

Comment: pretty sure that you can't.  I would suspect that the only thing you could do would be to actually change the namespace.  Aliasing like some of the answers below doesn't achieve what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799466/alias-a-namespace-globaly-for-the-entire-project
might help. Looks like the answer is you can't I'm afraid.

Comment: @C.Knight - and even that is in the consuming project rather than the consumed project, which seems to be what this question asks.

Comment: This is closer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805460/net-multiple-namespaces-for-single-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805460/net-multiple-namespaces-for-single-class), I think.

Comment: yeah, that's a beter link as an alias is just a second name.  Still gives an answer of 'it can't' though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**: Name the namespace of Entities classes (MyLibrary.App_Code.Entities) as MyLibrary.Entities

```
namespace MyLibrary.Entities
{
    public class Foo
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

**Option 2**: Using Directive

```
using Entities = MyLibrary.App_Code.Entities;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Main
    {
        var foo = new Entities.Foo();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.